# angular view doesn't update after second $compile

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have modal pop up in my code. This is the view:

```
<div class="modal fade in bs-example-modal-lg quickview__modal__bg" id="productModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" ng-controller="productController">
...
<span ng-bind="salePrice | currency">$10.00</span>
...
</div>
```

This is how I show pop up:

```
var utils = new function() { 
this.compileAngular = function(element) {
            angular.element('*[ng-app]').injector().invoke(['$rootScope', '$compile', function($rootScope, $compile) {
                $compile(element)($rootScope);
            }]);
        },
        this.showAngularModal = function(html) {
            var modal = $(html).modal();
            utils.compileAngular(modal);
            var dialog = modal.find('.modal-dialog');
            modal.css('display', 'block');                
            modal.modal('show');
        },
}
```

And this is how I try to update the view:

```
$scope.foo = function(){
      var data = ...;
      ...
      fooService.getPrice(data).success(function(result){
      $scope.newPrice = result && result.price ? result.price : 0;
      $scope.updatePrice();
   });
}

$scope.updatePrice = function(){
    ...
    $scope.salePrice = $scope.newPrice;
    ...
}
```

So, the problem: when I call `utils.showAngularModal()` first time and update price all is working as expected. But when I close bootstrap modal and reopen again view doesn't update. All values come as expected just looks like `scope` do not see changes. Could anyone, please, help me to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile something like this. Compile the element only with it's scope. compiling at rootScope level may cause some errors or unexpected output.

```
var throbberHolder = document.getElementById("throbber-mask");
$compile(throbberHolder)(angular.element(throbberHolder).scope());
```

or as your code, try something like this

```
 $compile(element)(angular.element(element).scope()); or
 $compile(element)(element.scope());
```